# very large XML file parsing sax vs stax vs vdt?

Tags: xml, parsing

My basic need is to parse a very large xlsx file (100MB, 1.5 million rows and 10-15 columns).

I know now that my best chance is to work on underlying XML files, as parsing xml files is done with much lower memory footprint than parsing xlsx (I can't avoid out of memory error if I simply try to parse xlsx file directly).

So far I was using SAX parser and it was working fine for smaller files but around at 60MB it failed and threw out of memory error. I want to know whether stax parser or vdt-xml is better in my case? Or for that matter, any other xml parsing method to handle huge files?

Comment: well, basically i am working on cassandra database where I want to read a xlsx file and put its data into the database (in a column family). For this, I am parsing the underlying xml files, creating SSTables from it and then inserting those sstables into the database. I am exhausted of trying direct xlsx parsing methods, all lead to OOM error

Comment: What language are you using? There should not be any reason for a SAX parser to run out of memory. Unless trees are really deep; the stack of open elements might grow too large then.  So it's probably your code handling of the element events that's growing out of memory. You don't show any code, but might those SSTables be growing in memory?? Find out what's using all that memory before blaming it on the parser.

Comment: When you use a SAX parser, the parser won't use any significant memory, but your application might: if you're running out of memory, then your application (or something else it calls) is at fault.

Comment: yeah u guys r correct. SAX has nothing to do with oom issue. I got the issue resolved now.It seems 2 factors matter here.First is how fast and good your processor is.Till now I was using a core 2 duo with 2 gb RAM 32 bit so it created some problems but now its ok, i am on a much better system.Second thing is that the number of unique strings in your xlsx file really matters. Since the sax parser loads what is called as 'shared strings' xml completely into memory, bigger its size more is the probability of getting OOM. When I tried a file only filled with numbers, even a 1GB file ran smoothly.